# How static local POD constants are initialized? Lazily or not?

Tags: c++

POD means primitive data type without constructor and destructor.

I am curious, how compilers handle lazy initialization of POD static local variables. What is the implication of lazy initialization if the function are meant to be run inside tight loops in multithreaded applications? These are the possible choices. Which one is better?

```
void foo_1() {
    static const int v[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
}

void foo_2() {
    const int v[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
}
```

How about this? No lazy initialization, but slightly clumsy syntax?

```
struct Bar
{
    static const int v[4];

    void foo_3()
    {
        // do something
    }
};

const int My::v[4] =  {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a static variable is initialized with constant data, all compilers that I'm familiar with will initialize the values at compile time so that there is no run time overhead whatsoever.

If the variable isn't static it must be allocated on each function invocation, and the values must be copied into it. I suppose it's possible that the compiler might optimize this into a static if it's a const variable, except that const-ness can be cast away.

Comment: +1: Note: casting away const'ness on a cost object then modifying it UB (as it may be potentially stored in read only memory).

Comment: - and **typically is** stored in read-only memory, as far as the popular compilers go.

Comment: @Adam: I believe that's only the case if the variable is static. A regular const variable on the stack is just stored on regular stack.

Comment: "I suppose it's possible that the compiler might optimize this into a static if it's a const variable" - careful, though: each invocation of the function, including recursive ones, must (subject to the "as-if" rule) have a different object, with a different address. So a compiler has to prove that the addresses can't be compared before it can common up the object.

Comment: @Steve Jessop, I hadn't considered that possibility. Good thing I don't write compilers for a living.

Comment: On the evidence, I think writing C++ compilers is a bit of a trial-and-error process for everyone.

Answer (score 2):

In `foo_1()`, `v` is initialized sometime before `main()` starts.  In `foo_2()`, `v` is created and initialized every time `foo_2()` is called.  Use `foo_1()` to eliminate that extra cost.

In the second example, `Bar::v` is also initialized sometime before `main()`.

Answer (score 2):

Performance is more complex than just allocation. For example, you could cause an extra cache line to have to be in cache with the static variable, because it's not contiguous with other local memory that you're using, and increase cache pressure, cache misses, and suchlike. In comparison to this cost, I would say that the incredibly tiny overhead of re-allocating the array on the stack every time would be very trivial. Not just that, but any compiler is excellent at optimizing things like that, whereas it can't do anything about static variables.

In any case, I would suggest that the performance difference between the two is minimal - even for inside a tight loop.

Finally, you may as well use foo_2()- the compiler is perfectly within it's rights to make a variable like that static. As it was initially defined as const, const_casting the const away is undefined behaviour, regardless of whether or not it's static. However, it can't choose to make a static constant non-static, as you could be depending upon the ability to return it's address, for example.

Comment: "the compiler is perfectly within it's rights to make a variable like that static" - same caveat as I gave Mark, the compiler has a fair bit of thinking to do before it could make a non-static variable static, because it has to know that its address is never compared to the address from another invocation of the same function. So if you pass a pointer to it into "unknown" code, it's probably impossible. In a multi-threaded implementation the compiler might not know that eg `printf` won't block on a mutex waiting for another `printf` call in another thread to pass something over for comparison.

Answer (score 1):

An easy method to find out how variables are initialized is to print an assembly language listing of a function that has static and local variables.

Not all compiler initialize variables in the same method.  Here is a common practice:
Before the `main()` method global variables are initialized by copying a section of values into the variables.  Many compilers will place the constants into an area so that the data can be assigned using simple assembly move or copy instructions.

Local variables (variables with local scope) may be initialized upon entering the local scope and before the first statement in the scope is executed.  This depends upon many factors, one of them is the `const`ness of the variable.

Constants may be placed directly into the executable code, or they may be a pointer to a value in ROM, or copied into memory or register.  This is decided by the compiler for best performance or code size, depending on the compiler's settings.

Answer (score 1):

On the technical side, `foo_1` and `foo_3` are required to initialize their arrays before *any* functions, including class constructors, are called.  That guarantee is essentially as good as no runtime.  And in practice, most implementations don't need any runtime to initialize them.

This guarantee applies only to objects of POD type with static storage duration which are initialized with "constant expressions".  A few more contrasting examples:

```
void foo_4() {
    static const int v[4] = { firstv(), 2, 3, 4 };
}

namespace { // anonymous
   const int foo_5_data[4] = { firstv(), 2, 3, 4 };
}
void foo_5() {
   const int (&v)[4] = foo_5_data;
}
```

The data for `foo_4` is initialized the first time `foo_4` is called.  (Check your compiler documentation to find out whether this is thread-safe!)

The data for `foo_5` is initialized at some time before `main()` but might be after some other dynamic initializations.

But none of this really answers questions about performance, and I'm not qualified to comment on that.  @DeadMG's answer looks helpful.

Comment: `foo_4` is allowed to be initialized before the first pass, and in C++0x it's required to be thread-safe.
`foo_5_data` can be initialized after the first statement of `main()`, the requirement is that it is initialized before the first use.

Answer (score 1):

You have a static initialization in all those cases, all your static variables will be initialized by the virtue of loading data segment into memory. The const in foo_2 can be initialized away if compiler finds it possible.
If you had a dynamic initialization, then initialization of variables in the namespace scope can be deferred until their first use. Similarly, dynamic initialization of local static variables in the scope of function can be performed during the first pass through the function or earlier. Additionally, compiler can statically initialize those variables if it's able to do that. I don't remember the exact verbiage from the Standard.